# MongoDB: Can't query for second value of duplicate key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

By some accident (while manually editing documents...) I ended up with several documents that have a duplicate key like so:

```
...
  "Directory": 
   {
    "x":"y",
    "z":1
   },
   "Directory":null,
...
```

I can't seem to query for that second "Directory" field. If I query for `"Directory":null` it doesn't return a single document (my guess is it "stops" searching when it finds the first (non-null) "Directory" field).

I tried [this](http://blog.mlab.com/2014/03/finding-duplicate-keys-with-the-mongodb-aggregation-framework/) solution but without success. It simply returns the first "Directory" field twice.

If nobody has a solution for my problem, I would be happy if there was at least some kind of possibility to tell the find() to start at the bottom of the documents, because if I reverse the order of the "Directory" keys (`"Directory":null` before the non-null Directory) it finds it without a problem..

I'm using Robomongo if that makes any difference..

Thanks a lot in advance!

PS: I don't want to create an index on the field!

Comment: No you didn't because it's simply not possible. There will be a "slight" difference between the two property names. It's probably a "space" or could be another non-printed character, but it is indeed there, You need to look carefully at this and then ideally rename or remove the incorrectly named property.

Comment: Yeah that's right. If you were to insert the same field twice, mongodb is going to create only one field but with a value that you provided to the second key.

Comment: please provide document sample with doubled entry

Comment: I (just now, for testing purposes) edited the document in Robomongo via right-click => Edit Document, and manually inserted the second Directory field and it went in just fine. Is there a possibilty to show non-printable characters? If I try to do the same thing via .insert() the behaviour is as Siddharth Ajmera described

Comment: This is the actual database entry copied from Robomongo: `"HostDirectory" : {
        "DefaultPageSize" : 10,
        "Group_id" : NumberLong(0),
        "IsActive" : false
    },
    "HostDirectory" : null,`

Comment: This is a known Robomongo bug which is already reported (https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/762). So what I learned today: Be careful while manually editing your documents in Robomongo (At least until this bug is fixed). Anyway, thanks for your efforts guys!